# Named query for entity that does not associate with a specific table

Tags: java, oracle, hql, named-query, quarkus-panache

I'm using Quarkus and Hibernate / Panache.

For this example, I have 3 tables (`table_a`, `table_b`, `table_c`) that I am joining together using a native query. In the project I'm working on, it's around 5 `JOIN` tables to retrieve the information I'm looking for.

`table_b` is purely a mapping / join table for `table_a` and `table_c`:

```sql
SELECT 
  a.id,
  a.name, 
  c.login_date 
FROM 
  table_a a 
  JOIN table_b b ON b.a_id = a.id 
  JOIN table_c c ON b.c_id = c.id 
WHERE 
  c.login_date > '01-MAY-21'
```

I'm porting the above to HQL. I've mapped all my `@Entity` classes with their respective `@Table`, along with their `@Column` names. We're good in that department.

```sql
SELECT 
  a.id,
  a.name, 
  c.loginDate 
FROM 
  TableA a 
  JOIN TableA b ON b.aId = a.id 
  JOIN TableB c ON b.cId = c.id 
WHERE 
  c.loginDate > '01-MAY-21'
```

I'm only looking for `name` and `login_date`. There is a bunch of other information stored in `table_a` and `table_c` that I don't want for this specific query. So I created an entity for this call:

```java
@Entity
@IdClass(LoginDetailsPk.class)
@NamedQuery(
    name = "LoginDetails.findFromDate",
    query = "FROM TableA a " +
            "JOIN TableA b ON b.aId = a.id " +
            "JOIN TableB c ON b.cId = c.id " +
            "WHERE c.loginDate > '01-MAY-21'"
)
public class LoginDetails extends PanacheEntityBase {

    @Id
    private int id;

    @Id
    private String name;

    @Id
    private String loginDate;

    public static List<LoginDetails> findFromDate(String fromDate) {
        // Eventually pass fromDate into find()
        return find("#LoginDetails.findFromDate").list();
    }

}
```

I'm having a hard time trying to understand why the `return` even works. When I invoke `LoginDetails.findFromDate(...)` and store it in a `List<LoginDetails>`, it works fine. However, when I try to access the list, I get a `ClassCastException` error.

```java
List<LoginDetails> details = LoginDetails.findFromDate(null);

for(LoginDetails detail : details) { // <------ Throws a class cast exception
   //...
}
```

After debugging, I'm noticing that generic type stored in my `List` isn't even my `LoginDetails` class; rather, it's an array of objects (`List<Object[]>`) with all my `@Entities` and the irrelevant information I'm not looking for.

I'm lost. Would it make more sense to move back to a native query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HQL is creating a `Object[]` for every row in the result, because you are not specifying any `SELECT`, and by default all the objects in the `FROM` clause are included in that `Object` array. If you want to return a `LoginDetails` object you need to create a constructor with all the attributes:

```
public LoginDetails(int id, String name, String loginDate) {
  this.id = id;
  this.name = name;
  this.loginDate = loginDate;
}
```

And then change the query to:

```
query = "SELECT new LoginDetails(a.id, a.name, c.loginDate) "
  "FROM TableA a " +
  "JOIN TableA b ON b.aId = a.id " +
  "JOIN TableB c ON b.cId = c.id " +
  "WHERE c.loginDate > '01-MAY-21'"
```

See https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-select